# Android Google Places API issue with key

Tags: android, google-places-api, production-environment, sha

I am beginner in Android. We are facing issues with Google Places API. We generated a SHA key for keystore file and added it to Google console. And use same file for building release apk, and released app. The app is working fine.

With few minor changes we update another version of app, then we got issues with places. Places API is not working.

We need to generate release build from same system, where we generated a SHA key from keystore file? I feel no need because from any system the SHA key is same for release keystore file.

And not added any configurations in Gradle file.

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("my-release-key.jks")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "my-alias"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
```

Because we used Sign an APK procedure from this documentation  https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

I am nor getting what exactly we are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working as a group on project, might be due to code merging. Project got deleted and it will cause problem for you. Just try to configure the place API again. It's the only hope for solving problem.

Comment: we have not added signingConfigs in gradle that is fine, right  ? Or we are missing any things

Comment: No you are not missing any thing. Just configuration of project might changes when merging. So just try to configure the api again.